# Is there a guna-based classification of Puranas in the Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, gunas, classification

https://ramanuja.org/sri/BhaktiListArchives/Article?p=sep96%2F0054.html

> One must watch out which purana is being quoted : The puranic evidence has
> to be from satvic puranas (as per classification in Mahabharata). Then only
> the purana has reasonable validity.  Or else the default validity goes only
> to the shrutis.